# How to show Variation as a product

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to show a variation when clicked on its link it displays information as a product

here is my product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    brand = TreeForeignKey('Brand', verbose_name='brand', related_name='products' , default='')
    category = TreeForeignKey('Category', verbose_name='Category', related_name='products' , default='')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 500 ,blank=True ,null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')

    objects = ProductManager()
```

here is my variation model

```
class Variation(models.Model):      

    VAR_CATEGORIES = ( 
            ('size' , 'size'), 
            ('color' , 'color'), 
        )

        product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
        category = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices = VAR_CATEGORIES)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        price = models.IntegerField()
        discount = models.IntegerField(blank=True ,null =True)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True , blank=True)
        sales_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True ,null =True)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to)
        slug = models.SlugField(default='')


        objects = VariationManager()

   def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product_detail" , kwargs={"pk":self.pk})
```

here is my product view

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "products/product.html"
    #template_name = "<appname>/<modelname>_detail.html"
```

here is my variation view

```
class VariationDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Variation
    template_name = "products/variation.html"
    context_object_name = 'variation'
```

and here is the urls.py

```
 url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$' , ProductDetailView.as_view() , name = 'product_detail'),


url(r'^((?P<pk>\d+)(?:/(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+))?/$' ,VariationDetailView.as_view() , name = 'variation_detail'),
```

and here is the template

```
{% for variation in object.variation_set.all %}
            <a href = "{% url 'variation_detail' variation.id variation.slug %}"><img src = "{{ variation.image.url }}"></a>
            {% endfor %}
```

it does show all the variations of my product but when i click on some variation then it doesnt do anything

where am i wrong?

Comment: Kind of off-topic but you're putting url's in the model. Your model should know nothing about how it is being used

Comment: How is Django supposed to tell the difference between your product and variation URLs? Also, both your `get_context_data` methods do nothing at all, you should remove them.

Comment: But the issue still remains: the URL patterns for product and variation are the same. There is no way that Django would ever call VariationDetailView, as the URL will always match the pattern for ProductDetailView.

Comment: thank you daniel ...i changed the url for variation...i am getting no reverse match